# How to test Vue components that need to react to child-sourced events?

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs

I’m having a hard time figuring out how to test single file Vue components that need to react to child-sourced events.

I have a Gallery component, which has any number of Card components as children, and must keep track of the Cards that are selected. When a card is clicked, it emits a custom event (card-click) that the Gallery listens for and reacts to by calling a select() function. Select() has some logic based on whether or not the Shift or Meta keys are pressed. I’ve created simplified versions of these components below:

**Gallery Component**

```
<template>
  <div class="gallery">
    <card v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :id="item.id"
      :key="item.id"
      class="galleryCard"
      @card-click="select(item.id, $event)">
      <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
    </card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Gallery",
  props: {
    items: {
      required: true,
      type: Array,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    select: function(id, event) {
      if(event.metaKey) {
        console.log('meta + click')
      } else {
        if (event.shiftKey) {
          console.log('shift + click')
        } else {
          console.log('click')
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

**Card Component**

```
<template>
  <article :id="id" @click="handleSelect($event)" class="card">
    <slot/>
  </article>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Card",
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  methods: {
    handleSelect: function(event) {
      this.$emit("card-click", event)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Using Jest, I’m trying to test the Gallery component’s `select()` function, which I’m [mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#using-a-mock-function) (`selectStub`), to make sure the correct Cards are selected when clicked.  When I trigger clicks on two of the cards, I expect to see something in the `selectStub.mock.calls` array, but there is nothing. I have also tried to emit the event How can I capture events that children emit in my test?

**Gallery Test**

```
import { createLocalVue, mount } from "@vue/test-utils"
import Gallery from "@/Gallery.vue"
import Card from "@/Card.vue"

const localVue = createLocalVue()

let wrapper
let items = [
  { id: "1", title: "First" },
  { id: "2", title: "Second" },
  { id: "3", title: "Third" },
]

describe("Gallery.vue", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(Gallery, {
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        items: items,
      },
      stubs: ["card"],
    })
  })

  const selectStub = jest.fn();

  it("selects the correct items", () => {
    wrapper.setMethods({ select: selectStub })

    const card1 = wrapper.findAll(".galleryCard").at(0)
    const card2 = wrapper.findAll(".galleryCard").at(1)

    card1.trigger('click')
    card2.trigger('click', {
      shiftKey: true
    })

    console.log(selectStub.mock)
  })
})
```

All properties (calls, instances, and timestamps) of selectStub.mock are empty. I have also tried emitting the `card-click` event [via vue-test-utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#asserting-emitted-events) `wrapper.vm.$emit()` function but it doesn't trigger the select.

How can I test the Gallery `select()` method to make sure it's responding correctly to a child-sourced event?